# 'EOF in multi-line statement' error message using Firefox with Selenium in Python when trying to connect trough Tor

Tags: python-2.7, firefox, selenium, raspberry-pi, tor

I am trying to use Firefox with tor on selenium using python. I am doing this on a raspberry Pi. The goal is to got Tor Start over every X search (in that case, 4). I try do to this in multiprocess. Everything work when I don't use FirefoxProfile. However, When I set the profile, I get this message:

> An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input file
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.pyc
>   The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid The error message
>   is: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (7, 0))

I really don't understand why... Do anyone have a solution?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.common.exceptions import InvalidSelectorException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from stem.util import term
import stem.process
import multiprocessing
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


start=1000
end=1004
port_tor= 9050
SOCKS_PORT = port_tor
nb_core=4


profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 5)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', port_tor)

def fonc1(x)
    display= Display(visible=0,size=(800,600))
    display.start()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
    driver.get("https://check.torproject.org/")
    elem4=driver.page_source
    driver.quit()

def fonc2(y):

    print term.format("Starting Tor:\n", term.Attr.BOLD)

    tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
      config = {
        'SocksPort': str(SOCKS_PORT),
      },
       init_msg_handler = print_bootstrap_lines,
    )
    results = Parallel(n_jobs=nb_core)(delayed(fonc1)(i) for i in inputs)
    tor_process.kill()


while start<end:
    inputs=[]
    count=0
    while count<4:
            inputs.append(start)
            count=count+1
            start=start+1
   fonc2(inputs)
```